# Python HTMLParser: AttributeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, html-parsing

I'm using HTMLParser (python 2.7)to parse pages I pull down with urllib2,and am coming across AttributeError exceptions when I want to store my data into a list in **feed** method. But if comment out the **__init__** method, the exception was gone

---

#### main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terms = []
        self.definitions = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # retrive the terms
        if tag == 'div':
            for attribute, value in attrs:
                if value == 'word':
                    self.terms.append(attrs[1][1])
        # retrive the definitions
                if value == 'desc':
                    if attrs[1][1]:
                        self.definitions.append(attrs[1][1])
                    else:
                        self.definitions.append(None)


parser = MyHTMLParser()
# open page and retrive source page
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/')
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
response.close()

# extract the terms and definitions
parser.feed(html)
```

---

#### Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/megachweng/Project/Anki-Youdao/combined.py", line 35, in <module>
    parser.feed(html)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/HTMLParser.py", line 116, in feed
    self.rawdata = self.rawdata + data
AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'rawdata'
```

Comment: sorry, because of some reason I cant use any third-part packages

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't initialize HTMLParser properly. Maybe you don't need to initialize it at all. This works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):  
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag
        # retrive the terms
        if tag == 'div':
            for attribute, value in attrs:
                if value == 'word':
                    self.terms.append(attrs[1][1])
        # retrive the definitions
                if value == 'desc':
                    if attrs[1][1]:
                        self.definitions.append(attrs[1][1])
                    else:
                        self.definitions.append(None)


parser = MyHTMLParser()
# open page and retrive source page
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://localhost/')
html = response.read().decode('utf-8')
response.close()

# extract the terms and definitions
parser.feed(html)
```

**UPDATE**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib2
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.terms = []
        self.definitions = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # retrive the terms
        for attribute in attrs:
            if attribute[0] == 'align':
                self.terms.append(attribute[1])
                self.definitions.append(attribute[1])


parser = MyHTMLParser()

html = "<table align='center'><tr><td align='left'><p>ciao</p></td></tr></table>"

# extract the terms and definitions
parser.feed(html)

print parser.terms
print parser.definitions
```

Output:

['center', 'left']

['center', 'left']

Comment: ya,it absolutely works, but any ideas how to store the attrs[1][1] into a list so I can access to it(print parser.terms --MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'terms')

Answer (score 0):

OK I got the solution,`super().__init__` cannot work, must hard code the name

```
def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
```